# <h3> within <a> within <li> strange firefox behavior

Tags: html, firefox, html-lists, anchor

I have a list of search result where i put ***h3 within a anchor within li*** like so

```html
<li>
  <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/">
    <h3>h3 within anchor within li</h3>
  </a>
</li>
```

Tests:

- Chrome, safari and opera => no problem
- Firefox and Firefox dev Edition => strange behavior

Please see the image below

[image]

Why Firefox render the code above like this ?

Note:

> no style are applied

Comment: I see the same thing in the image in Chrome on Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you put an element with default `display: block;` attribute: val (`<h3>`) *inside* an element with `display: list-item;` attribute:val... that is how the layout renders.

(To say nothing of the `<a>` tag, which I believe has `display: inline;` as a default.

You can avoid/ameliorate by adding css `h3{display: inline;}`, but it's not semantic HTML at that point. (List items should not contain headings - or, another way: inline elements)

By the way, this is how I see it in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Mac OS X 10.14.6:

[image]

Comment: I have also the same chrome version with Mac OS X 10.14 but it render it without this gap